# Which html doc type should I use?

Tags: html

I'm writing a web page. How do I know what doc type to use?:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

I believe the rationale behind using Transitional is that if your page uses deprecated html elements, the browsers will try to support them?

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

I'd use [`<!DOCTYPE html>`](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/07/html5-doctype), it's by far the easiest alternative, and it triggers standards mode in all modern browsers as [Anne van Kesteren noted several years ago](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/07/html5-doctype).

Comment: Gogo HTML5.  Google is using this on their pages now, too.  (They used not to have one at all.)

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

HTML 4 Strict DTD if you

a) Don't plan on using HTML 5 elements

b) Don't plan on really using xhtml with Content-Type of application/xhtml+xml

In this day and age you really shouldn't be "transitioning" or trying to using old, deprecated non-standard elements. Go standard all the way.

If you do plan on trying out HTML 5, by all means just use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` which is the HTML 5 DTD.

Comment: HTML = HTML 5, at least until the next standard revision (5.1? 6?).

Comment: HTML 5 is not widely supported, and it's still in writing. HTML 4 Strict is a stable DTD. You need to still include hacks if you plan on using HTML 5 in IE. Though yeah, I myself use HTML5 on my own sites which don't support IE.

Answer (score 3):

You should prefer strict above transitional/loose/invalid(!). Your first transitional example is invalid. It will let any browser render in non-standards/quirks mode, it won't let IE render in almost-standards mode.

[This site](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) contains excellent background information and a [compatibilty table](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/#handling). Here's an extract of relevance:

> #### Standards mode, more stable validation target
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> ```
>
> This doctype also triggers the standards mode, and the decade-old HTML 4.01 validity definition is stable. Please be sure to test your image alignment in Firefox, Safari, Chrome or Opera 9 or 10. Testing image alignment with Internet Explorer is inadequate however be sure to test in IE8, too.
>
> #### You’d like to use the Standards mode, but you still want to validate deprecated markup or you use sliced images in table layouts and don’t want to fix them
>
> ```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
> ```
>
> This gives you the Almost Standards mode (and the full Standards mode in really old Mozilla releases). Please note that your layouts based on sliced images in tables are [likely to break](http://www.mozilla.org/docs/web-developer/faq.html#gaps) if you later move to HTML5 (and, hence, the full Standards mode).

I'd say, go for HTML5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`, unless you want a more stable validation target.